# .NET Core/5 IConfiguration does not work on Ubuntu 20.10 x64 on Raspberry Pi 4 4GB

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-20.04, asp.net-core-5.0

I've had multiple apps installed on my `32 bit Raspbian` for the past 11 months or so with no problems to run them at all.
Recently, I wanted to experiment with MongoDB and I needed a `64 bit OS` version to get the latest build, so I decided to go with `Ubuntu Desktop 20.10 x64`. After installing `Ubuntu`, I tried starting one of my apps to see if all is well and it is not. At first, I thought it was a problem with `.NET 5` (I migrated the app just to see if it works), but the problem persisted with `.NET Core 3.1` as well, although it worked just fine before the OS switch.

The problems is that `IConfiguration` does not have values for the appsettings.json files. `IConfiguration` contains appsettings.json and appsettings.Production.json as providers, the providers contain the sections that I have defined, the sections contain the defined keys, but there are only null values on all of them.

I am unable to run the `32 bit` version of dotnet, so I cannot really pinpoint where the problem is coming from. Does anyone know why it might do that?

To be noted that I've also tried running another `.NET Core` app that I used to host on `Raspbian`, which is not developed by me, and I get the same results. Everything breaks because the configuration is broken.

Comment: How does your configuration look like and how are you reading it?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski ```"AppSettings": {"Tokens": ["token_val"]}``` is the section that I use for the particular app in question, and I'm using ```Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<MyAppSettings>();``` to parse them. It is working for Windows and was also working before I changed the RPi OS to 64 bits, so it shouldn't be a problem with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that I did not define the `WorkingDirectory` variable in the App.service file as I did before installing Ubuntu on my Raspberry. I tested this with an app and it's working when the variable is set, and not working when it's not.

The App.service file should look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=App

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/App/
ExecStart=dotnet /var/www/App/App.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=App
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://localhost:5000"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```